# Multiple files combined in one static library

Tags: c++

So I was wondering whether it's possible to have a static library with multiple files in it?  Right now I can use a static library attached to a specific .h and corresponding .cpp in other programs.  But when I try to add addional .h's and .cpps to the static library my other programs that try using them come back with error LNK2019.  Just want to know if its even possible before searching even more.

Comment: How *exactly* are you trying to "add" additional .h and .cpp files? What *exactly* are the error messages in question?

Comment: You don't add source files to a library. You add object files. And, yes, you can add as many object files as you like. When you link a program you have to tell it the name and location of the library.

Comment: So what im trying to do, in Visual Studios 2010, is create a static library project.  Then add several different unrelated .h and .cpp files to this static library project.  Then I've been copying the .lib file that is generated and pasting it in the Visual Studios->VC->lib directory and then putting the .h files in the static library project in the Visual Studios->VC->include directory.  I then opened the property manager for the project Im trying to use the library and go to, Linker->Input->additional Dependencies and included the .lib file.  But get error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Comment: SideBar: Don't do that (the copying libs to the VC/lib folder and the headers to the VC/include folder). You should consider those locations *off limits*. It is implementation-defined content. Instead, put your .lib and .h files in your own dir/lib and dir/include location, and specify where those folders are when configuring additional include folders and lib folders for projects that need to use them. That you haven't blown away a valid (and needed) existing .lib or .h files that are part of the implementation because of a name conflict is pure luck on your part.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering whether it's possible to have a static library with multiple files in it?

Yes. That's the whole point of a library — to be a single redistributable for a set of pre-built object files.

Comment: thats what I assumed but everytime i tried adding more than one it spits out LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty: That is not an effect of having a library with more than one object file in it; it's an effect of you having done something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty Do you mean add more than one library to a project? In visual studio you separate the library filenames with semicolons. As said by others, the whole idea of a library is to hold more than one object file.